# How Scaling will affect position of element in canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, textbox, zooming

I am having one canvas. I have added one text box to it using canvas.left and canvas.right property.And already there is a image inside that container. And am applying some matrix transform to my text box and image in order to zoom it.

```
 tb.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
```

But now the text box is getting moved to different position. But It should get zoomed along with the image. How to achieve that.?

Comment: Put the Image and TextBlock into a common container element (e.g. a Grid), and scale the container.

Comment: The Text box thickness should not get increased. If i use both of them in same container the sense it will affect the text box thickness. Thats why i have used separate containers for image and  text box.

Comment: So your `tb.RenderTransform` only contains a translation, no scaling?